# NPE when trying to use Jetty async HTTP client

Tags: nullpointerexception, jetty, firebase-cloud-messaging, future, jetty-9

When trying to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging by Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) with the help of [non-blocking Jetty HTTP client](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/http-client.html) in [a simple test case](https://github.com/afarber/jetty-newbie/blob/master/FcmNotRegistered/src/main/java/de/afarber/fcmnotregistered/Main.java) that I have prepared at GitHub -

```
private static final HttpClient sHttpClient = new HttpClient();
private static final Response.ContentListener sFcmListener = new Response.ContentListener() {
    @Override
    public void onContent(Response response, ByteBuffer content) {
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            return;
        }

        String body = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(content).toString();
        System.out.printf("onContent: %s\n", body);
        Map<String, Object> resp = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.parse(body);

        try {
            Object[] results = (Object[]) resp.get(FCM_RESULTS);
            Map result = (Map) results[0];
            String error = (String) result.get(FCM_ERROR);
            if (FCM_NOT_REGISTERED.equals(error)) {
                // TODO delete invalid FCM token from the database
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    sHttpClient.start();
    sHttpClient.POST(FCM_URL)
        .header(HttpHeader.AUTHORIZATION, FCM_KEY)
        .header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .content(new StringContentProvider(JSON.toString(REQUEST)))
        .onResponseContent(sFcmListener)
        .send();
}
```

but unfortunately the execution fails immediately with NPE:

```
2017-06-30 10:46:41.312:INFO::main: Logging initialized @168ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:682)
    at de.afarber.fcmnotregistered.Main.main(Main.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslClientConnectionFactory.newConnection(SslClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractHttpClientTransport$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(AbstractHttpClientTransport.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1600(ManagedSelector.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why does it happen please?

**UPDATE:**

I have switched to using `BufferingResponseListener` and the NPE is gone, but now the program prints `java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host` even though [the Google FCM endpoint](https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) is a well-known host:

```
private static final HttpClient sHttpClient = new HttpClient();
private static final BufferingResponseListener sFcmListener = new BufferingResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (!result.isSucceeded()) {
            System.err.println(result.getFailure()); // No route to host
            return;
        }

        String body = getContentAsString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.printf("onContent: %s\n", body);
        Map<String, Object> resp = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.parse(body);

        try {
            Object[] results = (Object[]) resp.get(FCM_RESULTS);
            Map map = (Map) results[0];
            String error = (String) map.get(FCM_ERROR);
            if (FCM_NOT_REGISTERED.equals(error)) {
                // TODO delete invalid FCM token from the database
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    sHttpClient.start();
    sHttpClient.POST(FCM_URL)
        .header(HttpHeader.AUTHORIZATION, FCM_KEY)
        .header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .content(new StringContentProvider(JSON.toString(REQUEST)))
        .send(sFcmListener);
}
```

I get the `No route to host` for any FCM_URL value I try, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `SslContextFactory` has helped me:

```
private static final SslContextFactory sFactory = new SslContextFactory();
private static final HttpClient sHttpClient = new HttpClient(sFactory);
private static final BufferingResponseListener sFcmListener = new BufferingResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (!result.isSucceeded()) {
            System.err.println(result.getFailure());
            return;
        }

        String body = getContentAsString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.printf("onComplete: %s\n", body);

        try {
            Map<String, Object> resp = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.parse(body);
            Object[] results = (Object[]) resp.get(FCM_RESULTS);
            Map map = (Map) results[0];
            String error = (String) map.get(FCM_ERROR);
            System.out.printf("error: %s\n", error);
            if (FCM_NOT_REGISTERED.equals(error) ||
                FCM_MISSING_REGISTRATION.equals(error) ||
                FCM_INVALID_REGISTRATION.equals(error)) {
                // TODO delete invalid FCM token from the database
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    sHttpClient.start();
    sHttpClient.POST(FCM_URL)
        .header(HttpHeader.AUTHORIZATION, FCM_KEY)
        .header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .content(new StringContentProvider(JSON.toString(REQUEST)))
        .send(sFcmListener);
}
```

The still open question I have is [how to retrieve the invalid FCM token that I have used in the Jetty HTTP client request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870396/how-to-pass-user-context-object-to-the-response-callback-of-async-jetty-http-cli), so that I can delete it from my database on the response...

Comment: Why did you need to add a `SslContextFactory`? `HttpClient` provides one by default, does it not?