# How to pass user context object to the response callback of async Jetty HTTP client?

Tags: callback, google-cloud-messaging, jetty, firebase-cloud-messaging, jetty-9

When sending notifications to single recipients over [Google Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), sometimes a response comes back (`200 + error:MissingRegistration`, `200 + error:InvalidRegistration`, `200 + error:NotRegistered`), which requires deleting the token of that recipient (because she for example reinstalled the Android app and the token has changed).

My question is:

How to pass that string (the FCM token) back to the response callback of the non-blocking [Jetty HTTP client](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/http-client.html)?

Currently my workaround is to add a custom HTTP header to my request:

```
X-token: APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...
```

and then I retrieve it in the response callback. But this is a hack, because FCM does not specify such a header and also I need to pass more custom data (the internal user id in my app) back.

Here is [my current source code](https://github.com/afarber/jetty-newbie/blob/master/FcmNotRegistered/src/main/java/de/afarber/fcmnotregistered/Main.java) with the custom HTTP header, how to change it please?

```
private static final String FCM_URL                  = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
private static final String FCM_KEY                  = "key=REPLACE_BY_YOUR_KEY";
private static final String FCM_RESULTS              = "results";
private static final String FCM_ERROR                = "error";
private static final String FCM_NOT_REGISTERED       = "NotRegistered";
private static final String FCM_MISSING_REGISTRATION = "MissingRegistration";
private static final String FCM_INVALID_REGISTRATION = "InvalidRegistration";

private static final String FCM_X_TOKEN              = "X-token";
private static final String TOKEN                    = "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...";

private static final Map<String, Object> REQUEST      = new HashMap<>();
private static final Map<String, Object> NOTIFICATION = new HashMap<>();
private static final Map<String, Object> DATA         = new HashMap<>();

static {
    REQUEST.put("to", TOKEN);
    REQUEST.put("notification", NOTIFICATION);
    REQUEST.put("data", DATA);
    NOTIFICATION.put("body", "great match!");
    NOTIFICATION.put("title", "Portugal vs. Denmark");
    NOTIFICATION.put("icon", "myicon");
    DATA.put("Nick", "Mario");
    DATA.put("Room", "PortugalVSDenmark");
}

private static final SslContextFactory sFactory = new SslContextFactory();
private static final HttpClient sHttpClient = new HttpClient(sFactory);
private static final BufferingResponseListener sFcmListener = new BufferingResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (!result.isSucceeded()) {
            System.err.println(result.getFailure());
            return;
        }

        String body = getContentAsString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        try {
            Map<String, Object> resp = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.parse(body);
            Object[] results = (Object[]) resp.get(FCM_RESULTS);
            Map map = (Map) results[0];
            String error = (String) map.get(FCM_ERROR);
            System.out.printf("error: %s\n", error);
            if (FCM_NOT_REGISTERED.equals(error) ||
                FCM_MISSING_REGISTRATION.equals(error) ||
                FCM_INVALID_REGISTRATION.equals(error)) {
                String token = result.getRequest().getHeaders().get(FCM_X_TOKEN);
                System.out.printf("TODO delete invalid FCM token from the database: %s\n", token);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    sHttpClient.start();
    sHttpClient.POST(FCM_URL)
        .header(HttpHeader.AUTHORIZATION, FCM_KEY)
        .header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .header(FCM_X_TOKEN, TOKEN) // Workaround, how to improve?
        .content(new StringContentProvider(JSON.toString(REQUEST)))
        .send(sFcmListener);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the token as a request *attribute* and the retrieve it back:

```java
httpClient.POST(url)
        .attribute(key, token)
        ...
        .send(new BufferingResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Result result) {
                Object token = result.getRequest().getAttribute(key);
                ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used `String token = String.valueOf( result.getRequest().getAttributes().get(key) );`